# Error in the first step of running this example: TensorFlowOnSpark on a Spark Standalone cluster

Tags: apache-spark, tensorflow, mnist

I have a problem with running this example [TensorFlowOnSpark on a Spark Standalone cluster (Single Host)](https://github.com/yahoo/TensorFlowOnSpark/wiki/GetStarted_Standalone):

After executing **mnist_data_setup.py** file, it extracts the MNIST zip files correctly. But by calling **extract_images(filename)** functions, it faces an error. Please see the error in the following:

```
 Extracting <open file 'FILE_PATH_IN_MT_PC/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz', mode 'rb' at 0x7ff3423e5c00>    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FILE_PATH_IN_MT_PC/mnist/mnist_data_setup.py", line 144, in <module>
    writeMNIST(sc, "FILE_PATH_IN_MT_PC/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz", "FILE_PATH_IN_MT_PC/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz", args.output + "/train", args.format, args.num_partitions)
  File "/FILE_PATH_IN_MT_PC/mnist/mnist_data_setup.py", line 52, in writeMNIST
    images = numpy.array(mnist.extract_images(f))
  File "FILE_PATH_IN_MT_PC/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py", line 42, in extract_images
    with tf.gfile.Open(filename, 'rb') as f, gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=f) as bytestream:
  File "FILE_PATH_IN_MT_PC/tensorflow/python/platform/gfile.py", line 452, in Open
    return GFile(name, mode=mode)
  File "FILE_PATH_IN_MT_PC/tensorflow/python/platform/gfile.py", line 215, in __init__
    super(GFile, self).__init__(name, mode, _Pythonlocker())
  File "FILE_PATH_IN_MT_PC/tensorflow/python/platform/gfile.py", line 63, in __init__
    self._fp = open(name, mode)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found
```

I would be so happy if someone helps me to find the solution for this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in the `open`, your provide a `file` type object instead of a `string` for the `name` variable.

I do more digging:

In `images = numpy.array(mnist.extract_images(f))`, `f` is a file object.

But `with tf.gfile.Open(filename, 'rb') as f, gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=f) as bytestream:`, this treats the argument passed by `images = numpy.array(mnist.extract_images(f))` as a filename.

This behavior does not appear in the latest version:
`https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py`

Comment: Thank you so much. The problem solved with the latest version.